# Scanf and printf a string with two words

Tags: c, string, io

I want to make a program to output a string that includes two words using `scanf` and `printf` functions.

This is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () 
{
    char str[20];
    scanf("%s%s", &str);
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

After I run the code the results are not what I want.

Input:

```
new version
```

Output:

```
new
```

What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: `char str1[20], str2[20]; if (scanf("%19s%19s", str1, str2) != 2) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); printf("%s and %s\n", str1, str2);`

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings to avoid similar questions in the future. Use `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` when you use gcc.

Comment: The array `str` will decay into a pointer as soon as you do something with it, except for things like the `sizeof`-operator. There is no need to use the `&` in `&str`. `str` will decay into a pointer to `char`, `&str` will decay into a pointer to `char` array with 20 elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can read an entire string including spaces using `[^\n]` specifier, which means read everything in the input stream until a newline character is found.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () 
{
    char str[100]; //20 characters is not much, addded a little more
    scanf("%99[^\n]", str); //size limit 99 + null byte
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `operator &` is not needed for char arrays in `scanf` and the input should be limited to the size of the destination buffer to avoid buffer overflow.

A character is 1 byte, in today's machines, generally speaking, that amounts to almost nothing, so be more generous with your `char` arrays if you can.

Comment: There are modern platforms where 1 byte is much, the ATTINY202 was released in 2018 and has 128 B RAM. The ATTINY4  is from 2009 and has 32 B RAM.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123, ah, fair point, I believe that the OP is not using any of those :) I did loosen a my remark a little.